# bxslider/firefox issue with slide alignment

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, bxslider

Hoping someone can give me a hand with this, I've used bxslider before and had no problems in firefox, however in this particular layout I'm having an odd issue where the slides seem to have 200px added to the left (though I can't find it).

If anyone can give me a hand or point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

The page in question is here: http://t4a.fileportal.co.uk/discover-curo/

Answer (score 1):

Just so people know, in the end we disabled the slider in Firefox using media queries, making the slides display as normal content:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {

    .bx-viewport {
        height: auto !important;
    }

    .slider, .bxslider2 {
        max-width: 100% !important;
        left: auto !important;
    }

    .bx-controls, .bx-clone {
        display: none;
    }

    .slider-container .contain-top {
        display: none;
    }

    .slider-menu {
        display: none;
    }

}
```